# *args and using the same arg twice

Tags: python, args

I have a function like this

```
def saveGraph(self): 
        f = open('graph.txt', 'w')
        f.write('graph graphname {\n')
        for i in self.edgeList:
            f.write('%s -- %s; [label = %d, weight - %d]\n' %(i[0],i[1], i[2], i[2]))
        f.write('}')
        f.close()
```

but some of my `i` are length 2. Is it possible to use `*args` that one of the arguments will be used twice? I mean:

```
def saveGraph(self): 
        f = open('graph.txt', 'w')
        f.write('graph graphname {\n')
        for i in self.edgeList:
            f.write('%s -- %s; [label = %d, weight - %d]\n' %(*i[0],*i[1], *i[2], *i[2]))
        f.write('}')
        f.close()
```

so `i[2]` is used twice and if there is no third element of `i` it just ignores it? (first and second elements are strings like 'A', and third element is int

The output should look like this:

```
graph graphname {
A -- B; [label = 1, weight - 1]
C -- A;
A -- D;
A -- E; [label = 1, weight - 1]
}
```

where `C -- A` and `A -- D` come from `i` with length 2, and `A -- B`, `A -- E` come from `i` with length 3 (third element is used twice).

Of course I could just use `if len(i) == 2: (...)` but i want to learn more about those `*`.

Comment: Could you add examples of the outputs you expect for different inputs?

Comment: Why won't you try your approach yourself?

Comment: @sophros that approach doesn't work and i wonder if somehow i can use twice or more the same argument when using `*`

Comment: @Saguro: please edit your task with the example and not refine it in comments which is unreadable.